# ymaps geolocation

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Неужели определение местоположения через api-maps v2.1 через provider: 'yandex', сейчас так неточно работает? И можно ли как-то на это повлиять?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: код лучше прикладывать не ввиде скрина, а текстом

Comment: Это дефолтная песочница https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите более точной геолокации, используйте [провайдер](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geolocation.html#method_detail__get-param-options.provider) '**browser**' и дайте странице доступ к этой самой геолокации устройства. Провайдер геолокации'**yandex**' определяет местоположение лишь по IP-адресу, полученному вами от интернет-провайдера. Пул адресов, из которого берётся ваш динамический (скорее всего) IP зачастую используется абонентами всего города или даже района. Определить точнее ваше местоположение с его помощью невозможно.

Если браузер запрашивает доступ к местоположению при включении **provider: 'browser'**, но позиция всё равно определяется неточно, значит ваше устройство не имеет более точных методов (gps, например) определения вашего местоположения. Попробуйте задать в настройках ОС ([пример для Win10](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/windows-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-3a8eee0a-5b0b-dc07-eede-2a5ca1c49088)) настройки геолокации для приложений.

Comment: Да, спасибо, так и поступлю

Answer (score 0):

Для повышения точности определения места положения используйте     `provider: 'auto'`

[Документация](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/geolocation.html)

Comment: К сожалению не помогает, город определяется некорректно